# How to include generic behaviour in contains string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to search if my collection property string contain many words at the same time. here my code with LINQ:

```
queryResult = questions.Where(q => q.proposition.Any(p => p.Libelle.Contains("string1") && p.Libelle.Contains("string2")));
```

I want to modify `p.Libelle.Contains("string1") && p.Libelle.Contains("string2")` to make it generic because sometimes I have many strings to search not 2. So I have an array of string: `string[] arrayStrings`. How to make my code fetch for all `propositions.Libelle` that contains at the same time all the words in my arrayStrings. Maybe I have 5 words in some cases.

For example:

```
arrayStrings = [aa,bb,cc,ll,bb]

propositions.Libelle:

 aabbccllllllppplmo

 jjjkkkkk

 aakk
```

I want to show only record: (`aabbccllllllppplmo`) that contain all words in `arrayStrings`.